# Internet speed in my Ubuntu 20.04 is painfully slow

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, dell-inspiron, wifi-driver, ubuntu-20.04

Hi I bought  a new Dell Inspriron 5501 quite months back. Never really use it a lot. But still after installing Ubuntu 20.04 my internet is really slow. I only get download speed of 100KB/second whereas it should be 6-10MB/second(around 100Mb/s speed) when I tried google speedtest It shows 0.5Kb/sec speed for download and 22-30 Mb/s for upload. If I had the same download speed it would have been enough. Keeping my laptop all all day I did all updated and upgrades and have seen all articles and videos and did not help.
I'm writing this in my phone so for any info that I should include please tell me in the comments.

The output of `$ dmesg | grep ath10k`

```
[    4.757415] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.762032] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    5.040354] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 1028:0310
[    5.040360] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    5.041163] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00140-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,mfp crc32 29eb8ca1
[    5.105831] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 4ac0889b
[    5.200882] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: htt-ver 3.60 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    5.295343] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   18.008823] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[   18.010108] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[   24.010724] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[   24.011647] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[   30.009366] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[   30.010640] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[   36.009945] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[   36.011334] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[   42.011827] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[   42.012971] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[   48.009416] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[   48.010704] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[   54.011943] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[   54.013351] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[   60.014821] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[   60.016166] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[   84.011663] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[   84.012795] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[   90.015108] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[   90.016122] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[   96.011744] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[   96.012943] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  102.012232] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  102.013386] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  102.178522] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  103.612775] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  108.011759] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  108.013078] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  114.011739] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  114.012901] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  120.011767] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  120.013119] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  126.011897] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  126.013112] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  132.011688] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  132.012862] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  138.009695] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  138.010798] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  144.011840] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  144.012938] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  150.113361] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  150.114693] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  162.251655] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  162.252923] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  168.271059] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  168.272461] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  174.279883] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  174.280840] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  186.092556] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  186.093811] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  192.003652] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  192.004995] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  194.532026] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  194.533303] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  203.942651] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  203.943955] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  222.000916] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  222.002124] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  222.813938] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  228.016354] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  228.017449] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  252.028275] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  252.029411] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  258.030383] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  258.031754] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  264.026714] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  264.027839] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  288.033685] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  288.034804] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  300.034578] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  300.035947] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  306.036490] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  306.037821] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  311.960399] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  311.961235] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  317.883515] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  317.884912] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  323.842546] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  323.843802] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  329.826190] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  329.827531] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  335.813916] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  335.815081] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  341.810950] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  341.812155] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  347.798763] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  347.800010] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  351.419238] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  353.788182] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  353.789394] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  359.780016] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  359.781268] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  365.773557] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  365.774799] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  371.768658] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  371.769688] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  374.309419] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  374.310855] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  377.761462] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  377.762641] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  383.758512] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  383.759648] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  389.756285] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  389.757513] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  395.752431] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  395.753400] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  401.749356] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  401.750323] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  407.745060] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  407.746214] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  413.747226] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  413.748684] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  419.752487] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  419.753930] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  425.750015] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  425.751176] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  437.753695] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  437.755005] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  443.750289] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  443.751526] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  449.749290] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  449.750455] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  455.748437] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  455.749750] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  461.749932] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  461.751324] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  467.745414] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  467.746594] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  473.743607] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  473.744741] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  485.740048] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  485.741275] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  491.742066] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  491.743320] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  497.740035] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  497.741303] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  503.737846] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  503.739056] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  509.731330] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  509.732485] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  515.730204] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  515.731434] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  521.728071] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  521.729500] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  527.728707] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  527.729909] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  533.727214] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  533.728373] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  551.726794] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  551.728254] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  557.729180] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  557.730558] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  575.730183] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  575.731451] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  587.730201] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  587.731209] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  599.732890] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  599.734112] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  605.732181] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  605.733399] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  611.728074] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  611.729264] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  641.721268] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  641.722758] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  647.719393] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  647.720532] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  653.717955] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  653.719091] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  659.716655] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  659.717839] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  671.713614] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  671.714776] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
[  677.712905] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
```

The error with invalid ht params rate was much more than the above mentioned ones,  I only attached less than half of them in here.

Thanks.

Comment: The manual says that the supported operating system is Ubuntu 18.04 **LTS** (64-bit):
 Download: [DL-PDF](https://dl.dell.com/topicspdf/inspiron-15-5501-laptop_users-guide_en-us.pdf). Test with a cat5e or cat6 network cable, it may be an operating system incompatibility and not the Driver.

Comment: The Dell 5501 sold with three WiFi options: Intel Wireless-AC 9462, Qualcomm QCA 61x4A and Intel AX201. Look on the web for a more recent Ubuntu driver for it. BTW, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is backwards compatible with 18.04 LTS, so that is likely *not* an issue.

Comment: @RpgBoss Yes I tried 18.04, 21.04 and even elementary OS, everything shows the same speed, but yes in windows I'm able to get full speed.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik My driver is QCA6174. The thing is when downloading something or while using apt, the download speed strikes the peak, and in matter of seconds it drops back to the mentioned 120-170Kb/s.

Comment: @ArjunKShibu You will need to download and install them with a portable usb disk. But if not via cable works I believe the problem is another. Try using another internet, but it's just a theory.